# Socket Programming: Send message from outside Silverlight app into Silverlight app, NOT across two Silverlight apps?

Tags: silverlight, sockets, messaging

I have little to no experience working sockets save for the last day or so of researching this specific scenario, so bear with me.

I have a standard .NET class library that is run from within a winforms desktop application. I also have a Silverlight Out-Of-Browser application that this class library/DLL must send messages to.

My issue with any example or sample I've found thus far is that they seem to always use the Silverlight application as the client and the outside source as the server.

In my scenario my DLL would need to attempt a socket connection to the OOB silverlight app (if it's running). If that connection succeeds, send a message to it.
So if I'm picturing this correctly, how would I about doing this in a lifecycle perspective?

The DLL would be loaded, and spin up a socket server, that server would then attempt a connection to a socket listener in the OOB silverlight app. If that connection succeeded, send a message?

This would also mean that when the OOB Silverlight app gets fired up, in the application startup, I would create the socket listener and set it to listen?

Thank you for any and all information. Again I've looked at several samples and read more than a few articles and my brain is fried. It's just not clicking with me for some reason.
And keep in mind this is for an "out of browser" instance of a Silverlight application. NOT a web hosted version.

This is the latest sample project I was looking at:

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/SocketsLight-Silverlight-Sockets-Framework.aspx

Comment: It seems like the more I research this, the more I find out that the way I'm hoping to utilize the SL client as the socket server just isn't how it's designed to work. I've since come up with a different approach with the help of a colleague. I'm using the SL as a client as it's intended and when I spin up my DLL, I'm creating a socket server and awaiting a client to connect to it. Then I spin up my SL application and create a client which connects to my DLL socket server and receives the message when it successfully connects.
This is causing some unwanted threading issues though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use COM automation back to front.  Silverlight OOB can connect to COM servers. What you want is the reverse - i.e. Silverlight OOB as a COM server. This is how you'd do it.

Design your Winforms app as a COM server that raises events that look like COM commands. e.g. instead of

```
event ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

do this

```
event SilverlightDoThis(arg1, arg2, ...)
```

Comment: Do you have a link to a sample or something a bit more detailed? Thx, I appreciate your help.